# Visual Studio 2010 - Datagridview Search Function with textbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, search, datagridview

I'm a beginner when it comes to coding on visual studio 2010, but I'm really enjoying it!

My end goal is to have a textbox that you put in text and it searches and selects the row that has that information.

This is the code I have so far:

```
 Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    Dim temp As Integer = 0
    Dim gv As Object
    gv = Me.End2End_Master_QueryDataGridView
    For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To gv.ColumnCount - 1
            If gv.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = Me.TextBox1.Text Then
                MsgBox("Item found")
                temp = 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If temp = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Item not found")
    End If

End Sub
```

I get a "NullReferenceException was unhandled" but it does find the item.

It also doesn't select that row because I'm not show on the correct code for this.

I am a beginner, and will need help in explanation's for some issues.

Please help!

Edit: This is the details of the exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=WindowsApplication1
  StackTrace:
       at WindowsApplication1.Form1.Button5_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ******\Form1.vb:line 39
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at system.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I have had a look and cant seem to make sense of it. I have given references to all my points in the code.

Comment: If you can debug the code shown without hitting a NullReferenceException, it must happen somewhere else. Read the exception details to find out where exactly things break. Include the stacktrace text and exception message to your question to help us help you.

Comment: I've added the exception message to my question

Comment: Can you please mark line 39 in code for us?

Comment: I have done this now